# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE success in interactive mode, fails in script

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector-python

I'm using ubuntu 16.04, mysql 5.6.34. python 3.5.2.

I cannot seem to get my script to perform the LOAD DATA INFILE statement, but it works fine on the same machine using python3 interactive mode .

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import mysql.connector
db = mysql.connector.connect(passwd=dbpwd,db=dbname,host=dbhostname,port=port_no,user=dbusername)
cursor = db.cursor()
insert_file = '/home/ubuntu/insert.csv'
db.get_warnings=True

q_event = ("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '%s' INTO TABLE my_table FIELDS TERMINATED BY "
    "',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\\\"' (col1,col2,col3)"
)
print(q_event.__repr__())
cursor.execute(q_event % insert_file) 
print(cursor.rowcount)
print(cursor.statement.__repr__())
print(cursor.fetchwarnings())
db.commit()
```

My output looks like this:

```
'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE \'%s\' INTO TABLE my_table FIELDS TERMINATED BY \',\' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY \'\\"\' (col1,col2,col3)'
0
'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/ubuntu/insert.csv\' INTO TABLE my_table FIELDS TERMINATED BY \',\' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY \'\\"\' (col1,col2,col3)'
None
```

The row count is always 0. No matter how I change the formatting of the `Load` statement, I can't seem to get the script result to change; it simply fails, without error.

Meanwhile, I things work just fine when running in interactive mode:

```
>>> import mysql.connector; db =  mysql.connector.connect(passwd="...",db="...",host="...",port=...,user="..."); cursor = db.cursor();db.get_warnings=True;
>>> cursor.execute("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '%s' INTO TABLE my_table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\\\"' (col1,col2,col3)" % "/home/ubuntu/insert.csv")
>>> cursor.rowcount
31
>>> cursor.statement
'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE \'/home/ubuntu/insert.csv\' INTO TABLE my_table FIELDS TERMINATED BY \',\' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY \'\\"\' (col1,col2,col3)'
>>> cursor.fetchwarnings()
>>>
```

Is there a reason this should work in interactive mode but not in a script?

Comment: In the script you are having `my_table` is that the table name you want to insert into ?

Comment: @AnouarZ Yes, sorry; fixed typo in write-up.

Comment: Do you see in mysql log what is the query excuted ?

Comment: @AnouarZ we're not logging all queries; errors are being logged; unfortunately, no errors are being generated by this